# How to make wordpress website https secure?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

Actually I applied ssl certification to my wordpress website but Its working only on the homepage. Except for Homepage every other page's url starts with http only. I want https applied to all pages. Can anyone help me.

Comment: I think it is better to ask there: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow attached image and change.
[image]

You can do this by adding the following code in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```